# How to execute Javascript inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using a javascript code which automate serveral actions in webpage using chrome development console (ctrl + shift + J). But unfortunately when the code is in the middle of executing, the web page disconnect us (it would not send us data nor allow the browser to send data- disconnected from the chat windows for example) so we have to reload the page again, which will destroy any variables modified by the script.

This is a part of my script for example, since the whole pack of it is too large to be displayed clearly:

```
var $balance = $("#balance"),
  $statusBar = $(".progress #banner");

function getStatus() {
  var a = $statusBar.text();
  if (hasSubString(a, "Rolling in")) return "waiting";
  if (hasSubString(a, "***ROLLING***")) return "rolling";
  if (hasSubString(a, "rolled")) {
    var b = parseInt(a.split("rolled")[1]);
    return lastRollColor = getColor(b), "rolled"
  }
  return "unknown"
}

function getBalance() {
  return parseInt($balance.text())
}
```

Since javascript will be gone after reload a page, I am thinking about the idea of execute a javascript inside the iframe, so when I'm reload the iframe it would not affect the running script. But my problem is I only have the script for running directly into the objective page, but not the one which have the iframe.

It would be grateful if you guys can give me some solution. Many thanks!

Comment: For starters is iframe source on same domain as page? If not you have no access to it due to *"same origin policy"*. Beyond that your question is far too vague and is missing any code to represent actual problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post actual code and elaborate on "the web disconnect us" which sounds like your script reloads something

Comment: Thank you for reply me! I'm an amateur in coding so it is nice if someone could help me solving problems!

@charlietfl: the iframe is outside of the domain. I just want to create some workaround for my script to be executed through webpage reloads. Can you help me with any alternative idea than iframe? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you man!
@mplungjan: I mean in the chat session for example, the webpage disconnect so the user cannot send text to server and it refuse to deliver message to the client also.

Comment: Look into using Tampermonkey user script extension perhaps. Allows you to run your own script without using console

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for your suggestion. But I still can't manage tampermonkey script to continue running after page reload. It started from the beginning just like chrome console.